# Проблемы с координатами в html canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, события

Всем доброго дня!

Подскажите, как вычислить координаты относительно левого верхнего угла canvas'a по событию touchstart?

Делал это так:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("cvs")
cvs.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - $(comm).offset().left;
    var y = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - $(comm).offset().top;
    ....
})
```

возникла проблема, в том, что e.targetTouches[0].pageY - меняет свое значение при прокрутке, решил по-другому:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("cvs")
cvs.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.touches[0].clientX - $(att).offset().left;
    var y = e.touches[0].clientY - $(att).offset().top;
    ....
})
```

но тут тоже оказалась проблема, при прокрутке - все замечательно, а вот при изменении масштаба страницы - снова бред....

Если вопрос непонятен, то объясню еще раз. Надо сделать так, что бы независимо от того где находится canvas на страницы при таче по левому верхнему углу координаты были [0;0]

Comment: а через CSS его left/top не установлены?

Comment: установлены left:0; top:0. канвас обернут в див, у дива position:relative; у канваса position:absolute;

Comment: А канва у вас случайно не width:100%; height: 100% ?))

А почему не стали использовать position:fixed?

Comment: Не, у канвы жестко размеры забиты (в пикселях), а на счет position:fixed - практически никогда я такое не использую. А есть основание полагать, что в этом проблема?